# Identity server 4 token retrieve with username and password

Tags: identityserver4

Through visual studio 2022 I created a web app that hosts an IDS4 server for generating tokens and the login system via asp.net core identity.

As a client I have an MVC web application that has a series of protected pages, when a user tries to reach these pages he is redirected to the IDS4 server which by logging in via asp. net core identity (interactive login and password) receives the token issued by the IDS4 server which I then use in the MVC web app.
Then I have a series of micro services with the APIs protected via the [Authorize] tag as I have them in the MVC webapp, what I would like to do now is to understand if there is a method to get a token from the IDS4 server for example from an android app by simply passing the user and the password without using the client ID and the SECRET, to then use the token received to access the micro services in the body of the access request to the APIs exposed by the micro services.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not quite an answer, but the comments don't allow enough characters to explain...)

Hosting an identity provider involves 3 parties: the owner of the data (eg. your platform), the  consumer of the data (eg. some other developer), and the user (the developer's customer). Whoever wants to consume your data/api needs to create an OAuth Client on your platform. This will give him a ClientId and ClientSecret, which he includes in his own hosted api.

The end user (his customer) visits this website, and the website needs to show/process data that's not known to him, but is known to your website. So the user needs to sign into your website, and specify what data from your platform (api-scopes/identity-scopes) he wants to be shared with the other website. This will result in **AllowedScopes**, and your website generates a token which is passed on to the consuming website. The consuming website can then query your api and retrieve the information the user actually approved of.

The point of what I've written here is: The consuming website WILL need a client-id and secret on your platform because that's how OAuth/SAML work...

If you and your user are the only parties involved, and don't share your data with third-parties, then you actually only need to use [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#examine-register).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have micro services that are protected by IDS4 authentication, then I have a web application in MVC that uses the normal login hosted on the IDS4 server that authenticates via the asp.net core identity API and I receive the token to browse the protected pages.  The point is access to microservices via SPA pages or android mobile applications, I was expecting an API on the IDS4 server which, passing my username and password, returned me a token which I would then use to access the microservices.